# git, create remote branch in the same place as another remote

Tags: git, git-remote

How can I create a remote branch based on another already existing remote without checking out to creating local and pushing to the remote.

To elaborate a little, at `repo1` I am at `branchA`. There exist an `origin/branchB` and I want to create a `origin/branchC` in the same place as B. A is different from both. I know `B` is a duplicate to `C` in `repo1` but at another `repo2` eg, it will be different.

(I know the question sounds weird but in my large company environment the production build needs to have a single branch name, but checking all repos is impossible due to space limitations. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to create a remote `branchC`, which starts on the same commit as `origin/branchB` :

```
git push origin origin/branchB:branchC
```